# How can I use existing variables and their values as parameters for a function (Python)?

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

I believe what I am asking is pretty simple, however none of my searches have turned up useful information.

So, all I want is to be able to access a preexisting variable in a program and use its value as a parameter of one of my own functions.

```
print("Please enter a number")
number = int(input())

def addTwo(number):
    newNumber = number + 2
    print("Your number plus two is ", str(newNumber))
```

So if you entered the number 4:

```
Please enter a number
>>> 4
Your number plus two is 6
```

That's all I need and hopefully it is simple! Thanks!

Comment: You just need to call your function with `addTwo(number)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BrenBarn suggested

```
print("Please enter a number")
number = int(input())

def addTwo(number):
    newNumber = number + 2
    print("Your number plus two is ", str(newNumber))

addTwo(number)
```

You simply pass parameters to your function which takes exactly one argument `number`.